# How can i load external json data in highcharts to show the bar chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

This is my json data. I need x-axis as Country_Name and value as y-axis. I need dynamically plot the bar chart using highcharts and changing the Country_Name and value show in json data automatically update the bar chart. I am very new at highchart and I am strungling to make bar chart.

```
 var recipient_country =  [{"Country_Name": "MYANMAR", "value": 143},
  {"Country_Name": "MONGOLIA", "value": 46},
 {"Country_Name": "ZIMBABWE", "value": 1},
  {"Country_Name": "Bahrain", "value": 1}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to think EXT JS column charts
Link: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/charts-kitchensink/#basic-column

Comment: I need highcharts code for the above json data